# C# Visual Studio's Text to Answer

Tags: c#-4.0

This is kinda of a Noobie what about I am gonna ask but I am trying to get my Program to work I do not know how to Ask a question in a text box hit the button and it outputs the answer; I Have been researching this for a while I know how to get everything else to work.

Comment: Did you remember to add magic dust?...Seriously, though, what kind of question are you asking?...and what kind of answer are you expecting?  I'm guessing maybe you are attempting to do a web search?

Comment: @idle_Mind I am trying to setup up where if you type "Hey" into console it will output a answer like "Welcome". I was drunk when I posted that. xD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So a simple **Console** app example:

```
    static void Main()
    {
        bool exit = false;
        string response;
        while (!exit)
        {
            Console.Write("Command ('Exit' to end): ");
            response = Console.ReadLine();
            switch (response)
            {
                case "Hey":
                    Console.WriteLine("Welcome");
                    break;

                case "unicorns":
                    Console.WriteLine("...are awesome!");
                    break;

                case "Exit":
                    exit = true;
                    break;

                default:
                    Console.WriteLine("Unrecognized command!");
                    break;
            }
        }
        Console.Write("Press Enter to Quit");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```